# How to determine if char origin is from keyboard (while reading file content)

Tags: java, opencsv

I'm parsing CSV files, and I might sometime bump into illegal files , like *jpeg* or *pdf* and etc...

So when I parse the file content I want to determine if the char is legal (came from keyboard) like *a 5 & % !* and etc...

But not chars like this  : *�  ַ* and other weird chars that can be found inside *images* *pdfs* and other files

I don't want to check mime type of the file and I prefer not to add several third party jars to solve this problem , I want to figure out that the file that is being parsed is valid by looking into its chars

Is the something similar to `Character.isLetterOrDigit` that can tell if the char is a char that was typed from keyboard or some weird char like *�  ַ*

*One more thing I need to be able to accept chars of various languages (not only English)
so I want to avoid doing plain char comparing like `c <= 32 && c >= 126` and etc...

---

B.t.w in general I'm looking an answer to problem described in this question [CSV file validation with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/644539/617373)

Comment: Why don't you check the file name for ending in .csv?

Comment: @André cause for example `.txt` is fine for me too...  I don't want to limit myself by extension, but a content...

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a built-in function, I don't know of one. You can, however, look at the `char`'s ascii value and filter to your liking. Check out [this ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for the values.

You can say, for example, if the ascii value is `<= 32 && >= 126`, you will not accept it; otherwise, you will:

```
public boolean isValid(char c) {
    if (c <= 32 && c >= 126) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

If you operate on an entire line/`String`, you might be able to use this to strip away your valid characters and determine if any invalid characters remain:

```
public boolean isValid(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("\\w|\\p{Punct}", "").length() == 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , I'm aware of this approach , but prefer some built in method (if exists) ,also I might bump into different languages chars , so their ascii code may vary...

Comment: @Daniel You should have no problems with different language chars using this method (I'm assuming you mean chinese characters and the like?). You are specifically defining your _accepted_ range of values. Values not in that range will be "invalid", different languages included! Furthermore, if you operate on `String`s as opposed to `char`s, maybe regex might help? I've added another function though I don't really know the corner cases for this one, if any.

Comment: One example is ascii code ...125 126 are valid char signs and 127 is del (not real char) and while 128,129... are valid chars letters, <-- This reason and the fact that I dont wanna mess with ascii code , instead I prefer a ready made proven api